# Training data for question-answering with model from huggingface or any other open-source

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers

I am relatively new in AI using this model.
https://huggingface.co/MaRiOrOsSi/t5-base-finetuned-question-answering

I have code like this.

```
model_name = "MaRiOrOsSi/t5-base-finetuned-question-answering"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelWithLMHead.from_pretrained(model_name)
question = "If I need to give one banana to each person, how many people can I give?"
context = "There are two banana and one orange."
input = f"question: {question} context: {context}"
encoded_input = tokenizer([input],
                         return_tensors='pt',
                         max_length=512,
                         truncation=True)
output = model.generate(input_ids = encoded_input.input_ids,
                        attention_mask = encoded_input.attention_mask)
output = tokenizer.decode(output[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
print(output)
```

It could give answer as "two" and it is still okay. But if I change the question and context like this, it is not okay.

```
question = "Did the user answer all requested information?"
context = "Agent: Could you please provide us user id and postal code? User: Here is my postal code, 11111111"
```

It is not okay. I know that there are limitation on this model. My question is

1. Is there a better model to handle this kind of question-answer? (Except for ChatGPT. I have tested on ChatGPT and it can handle correctly.)
2. Is there a way I should ask? Or do I need to train more for this model?

Thank you.

Comment: The model was trained on wikipedia and imdb snippets, but the task you are trying to perform seems to require some reasoning over dialogs. You should first identify the features of your text and check if there is a publicly available model that was trained on a dataset with similar features. Maybe FLAN will yield better results.

Comment: Thank you @cronoik. FLAN is something that I can use.